# How to use overflow: hidden and make elements overflow on top without using position: absolute?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web

I'm using react and I would like to create an animation using `react-collapsed` that would collapse the upper half of the target component.

So right know It will decrease container size to half of the child's size and applies `overflow: hidden`. This will make the child overflow on the bottom. Is there a way to make it overflow on the top?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use relative positioning of the child of the collapsed element. Then set the top position to 100%. This refers to the size of the parent container. And translate the child -100% which refers to the size of the child element.

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  top: 100%;
}

.collapsed {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* just some styling */
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsed">
  <div class="content">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium  doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
  </div>
</div>
```